# iOS - Gesture and uislider

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uislider, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm developing an app for iOS with a menu like Facebook with [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController), a nice project to manage the horizontal gesture on the app.
The problems borns when I put into the view an UISlider... I can't touch it nice because the sliding motion of the sliders is being mistaken as a swipe left/right.
[This](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController/blob/master/ECSlidingViewController/Vendor/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController.h) is the header file of che class with all the methods and this is the code to put in the main view:

```
if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
  }

  if (![self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController isKindOfClass:[UnderRightViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UnderRight"];
  }

  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

This last line is the code that integrate the gesture on the app.
Is there a method to disable the gesture only on the uislider?

Thanks at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a delegate to `self.slidingViewController.panGesture` and have it ignore touches that are on a `UISlider` view. The following question and answer have all the information you need: [Pan gesture interferes with UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601718/pan-gesture-interferes-with-uislider).

Comment: I just checked the ECSlidingViewController, and they aren't assigning a delegate for `panGesture`, so you can use the answer linked above without issue. If they change their code in the future to use a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` then your code will break.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have some difficulty with English and Obj-c :D
I must create the delegate of ECSlidingViewController?
And then, I must implement something like this:
if ([self.slidingViewController.panGesture isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.panGesture.enabled=NO;
    }
?

Comment: So your main view controller needs to be a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, and then you need to add a method to the class called `- (void)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer shouldRecieveTouch:(UITouch*)touch`. The code for this method is in the linked question. After adding the gesture recognizer to your main view, add the following line: `self.slidingViewController.panGesture.delegate = self;`