# Objective C - UIPanGestureRecognizer selector not invoked with UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to using **UIPanGestureRecognizer** and **UITapGestureRecognizer** on UISlider. tap is working fine i am facing problem with **UIPanGestureRecognizer**. I need to call **handleTransactionPan** method on changing value of UISlider but it is never being called because of its delegate method.

How can i invoke the **selector** while keeping the delegate methods to fire? Here is the code for what i have done so far.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pr=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTransactionPan:)];
    pr.delegate=self;
    [slider addGestureRecognizer:pr];

    tr=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tr.delegate=self;
    [slider addGestureRecognizer:tr];

}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if(gestureRecognizer==pr)
    {
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried using pr.state inside UISlider value change method but the state of pr is not **UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded** instead it is **UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible**

Comment: not able to solve this yet so i dicided to create custom UIControl i uploaded it on githuh threestatesbutton [Link](https://github.com/ghazi256/ThreeStatesButton)