# UISlider and Pan Gesture Recognizer do not mix

Tags: swift, pan

As asked here: [Pan gesture interferes with UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601718/pan-gesture-interferes-with-uislider?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Gesture problem: UISwipeGestureRecognizer + UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765661/gesture-problem-uiswipegesturerecognizer-uislider/4766026#4766026) I cannot get UISlider to work with a pan gesture where in my navigation controller I have a class that has a "back" button capability.

The answers mention that I should add a delegate to my class as such

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if let view = touch.view, view == slider {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

However, this method never gets called. I have tried about 15 ways to set the delegate for this class, but I honestly have no clue what to set at the delegate.

```
let myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:nil)
myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Nothing to this effect works. Could someone clearly explain how I can fix this problem. I have tried every approach on the first 2 pages of google. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765661/gesture-problem-uiswipegesturerecognizer-uislider/4766026#4766026) code more precisely, then code is checking class as a UISlider not object of UISlider.

So in swift you have to write like this

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let view = touch.view
    if  view is UISlider { // check class as a UISlider
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

I didn't run and check my code, if any editing required then do and if you need any help then add comment.

> Edit

For `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, check this post : 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-detect-edge-swipes

Comment: Yes you're probably right but my issue is that the method never gets called. Also I'm not trying to add an action, so this post does not help.

Comment: You need to add gesture on your view `view.addGestureRecognizer(myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare edges

In Swift it will looks like

```
let myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:nil)
myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
myScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.edges = .left //.right, .top, .bottom
```

Comment: I don't see if you add your gesture recognizer to your view.