# Swipe gesture interrupts UISlider control in iOS 13, but not previous iOS versions

Tags: swift, uislider, ios13, uiswipegesturerecognizer

**Note:** This is the iOS 13 beta, but also could apply to the official release tomorrow.

**Update 2:** I replaced it with a larger thumb image, and I'm still having a problem.

**Update:** It looks like it still controls continuously if I'm super precise about touching the thumb on the slider. But why is this changed, and how can I make it control like before?

I have a swipe gesture recognizer added to my view:

```
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

Later on, I add a UISlider to the same view:

```
        let slider = UISlider()
        let sliderLength:CGFloat = 175
        slider.frame = CGRect(x:0,
                              y:CGFloat(customHeight) - 35,
                              width:sliderLength,
                              height:35)


        slider.minimumValue = -1.2 
        slider.maximumValue = 0.6
        slider.setValue(Float(snowSliderValAdder), animated: false)

        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.updateSnowSliderValue(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        view.addSubview(slider)
```

What used to work fine, now behaves poorly in iOS 13. I can move the thumb on the slider if I move it very slowly, but if I do any kind of a swiping motion, the thumb on the slider stops moving and the gesture is triggered. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Is the slider in a card modal view controller? The dismiss gesture might be interfering with you sliding gesture.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` to check if the swipe occured on the slider, and if so, return false?

Comment: @Gereon - I got it to work now. I needed to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to my view and assign the swipe delegate to self.

Comment: I'm curious to see the solution - why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Hi @Gereon I added an answer.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue and managed to resolve it by doing the following:

Add a panGesture ,that does nothing, to your sliders and set their cancelsTouchesInView propery to false.

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action:nil)
                    panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
                    slider.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Now your sliders should slide like a knife cutting a butter with no swipe interruption.

Comment: Where did you graduate from? Hogwarts?

Comment: This doesn't work (May 2020) and feels very "hack-y". What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: This SO thread has the correct answer that shows the proper way of doing it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765661/gesture-problem-uiswipegesturerecognizer-uislider/4766026#4766026

Answer (score 1):

What I did was use a gestureRecognizer function to stop any gestures if a touch was detected on my UISliders. Make sure to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and set the UISwipeGestureRecognizer's delegate to self.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

   if touch.view == self.view.viewWithTag(viewTags.MySlider.rawValue) {
        return false
   }
   else if touch.view == self.view.viewWithTag(viewTags.AnotherSlider.rawValue) {
        return false
   }

   return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**

The Problem can be solve using delegate method of gesturerecognizer as below

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view?.isKind(of: UISlider.self) ?? false {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find something during the last hour. It looks like the swipe gesture recognizer as interferance with UISlider.

The problem appears only if you are using right/left direction. Perhaps you should wait before update your app or change your UI to use the up/down swipe gesture.

At this time the slider works normally if you wait a bit before you move your finger. Hoping Apple will fix it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the method for a custom view your have created can also solve the problem.

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return gestureRecognizer.view is Your_Custom_View
}
```