# How to prevent a Cell from swiping when the UISlider inside of it is swiped

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uislider

I have a horizontal `CollectionViewCell` with a `UISlider` inside of it. When I try to drag the slider the cell swipes.

**How can I prevent the cell from swiping when I drag the slider?** I don't want to lose the ability to swipe the cell itself meaning when I swipe the cell it should move to the next cell which the slider has nothing to do with.

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var slider: UISlider = {
        let slider = UISlider()
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // ...
        return slider
    }()


    // slider is pinned towards the bottom of the cell
}
```

Comment: try changing continuos property of slider  to no and check once by default this value is set to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer [from here](https://github.com/WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider/issues/81#issuecomment-560405018) which got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040355/4833705):

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action:nil)
    panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    slider.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}
```